# connecting Redshift DB to Java Application using temporary Credentail

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect redshift DB to java application using temporary credetial
I am passing Secretkey ,sessionToken and  accessID to jdbc url
its giving error like sessionToken is invalid
but when i use same token to connect Toad point it works fine
has anybody connected redshift db to java application using temporary credential?
I don't want to use Profile file located in my system generated by CLI
I am getting credential from java code itself using adfs URL

Comment: Please show your code to connect to Redshift

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.